# Making a customized forest plot of two groups using R

Tags: r, graph, plot, categories, percentage

I would really like to make a plot like this one using R. I've experimented with the `forest()` command from the `metafor` package but can't seem to create anything comparable. I also have two groups, multiple categorical variables, and percentages - basically, exactly the same kind of data shown in this plot. Could anyone give me suggestions on how to solve the problem using R?

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using these colours intuitively makes me to suggest the `ggvis` package that uses exactly those two colours (by default although obviously you can change them) to do this:

Look at the following example:

**Data**

```
y <- letters[1:10]
x <- runif(10)
gender <- rep(c('male','female'),5)
df <- data.frame(y,x,gender)
```

**Solution**

```
library(ggvis)
df %>% ggvis(x= ~x, y= ~y, fill= ~gender) %>% layer_points()
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you need to remove grid lines to show exactly like the graph you posted you could do the following:

```
df %>% ggvis(x= ~x, y= ~y, fill= ~gender) %>% layer_points() %>%
  add_axis('x', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') )) %>%
  add_axis('y', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') ))
```

Comment: Wow thanks! How do I put the blue and orange dots on the same lines like they are in the original?

Comment: This is only an example data set I made. If the `c` category (for example) has both female and male entries then they will show on the same lines. In my example no males and females overlap :). And I 'm happy I could help :). If you replicate this with your data it will show exactly the same.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. I just applied it to my own data and it worked out perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `ggplot`, just an example with two groups:

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(type=c("Music","Physics","Music","Physics"),gender=c("Male","Male","Female","Female"),val=c(10,20,30,40))
ggplot(data,aes(x=val,y=type,color=gender))+geom_point(size=3)+theme_bw()
```

[image]